# Incremental Days between dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a long list that needs the days between dates

```
ClientID <- c("00932", "00932", "00932")
Visit <- c("2018-11-10", "2018-11-20", "2018-11-25")

ClientID    Visit
00932    2018-11-10
00932    2018-11-20
00932    2018-11-25
```

I need a new column that says

```
ClientID    Visit    Days
00932    2018-11-10    0
00932    2018-11-20    10
00932    2018-11-25    15
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Visit` to date class and for each `ClientID` subtract the `Visit` with the minimum `Visit` date.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Visit = as.Date(Visit, '%m-%d-%Y')) %>%
  group_by(ClientID) %>%
  mutate(Days = as.integer(Visit - min(Visit))) %>%
  ungroup

# ClientID Visit       Days
#  <chr>    <date>     <int>
#1 00932    2018-11-10     0
#2 00932    2018-11-20    10
#3 00932    2018-11-25    15
```

**data**

```
ClientID <- c("00932", "00932", "00932")
Visit <- c("11-10-2018", "11-20-2018", "11-25-2018")
df <- data.frame(ClientID, Visit)
```

Comment: This solution creates 2 empty columns in my dataframe, both Visit and Days are not N/A

Comment: It works fine using the data in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have multiple `ClientID` and want to calculate the `Days` on that level:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

ClientID <- c("00932", "00932", "00932")
Visit <- c("11-10-2018", "11-20-2018", "11-25-2018")

df <- data.frame(ClientID, Visit)

df %>%
  group_by(ClientID) %>%
  mutate(Visit= mdy(Visit),
         Days= as.numeric(Visit-lag(Visit)))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace_na(., 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ClientID Visit       Days
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 00932    2018-11-10     0
2 00932    2018-11-20    10
3 00932    2018-11-25     5
```

Adding another `ClientID` and two observations to demonstrate it better:

```
ClientID <- c("00932", "00932", "00932", "00935", "00935")
Visit <- c("11-10-2018", "11-20-2018", "11-25-2018",  "11-20-2019", "11-25-2019")

df <- data.frame(ClientID, Visit)

df %>%
  group_by(ClientID) %>%
  mutate(Visit= mdy(Visit),
         Days= as.numeric(Visit-lag(Visit)))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace_na(., 0))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  ClientID Visit       Days
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 00932    2018-11-10     0
2 00932    2018-11-20    10
3 00932    2018-11-25     5
4 00935    2019-11-20     0
5 00935    2019-11-25     5
```

Adding the function, as it was asked in the comments:

```
days_func <- function(df){
  
  df %>%
    group_by(ClientID) %>%
    mutate(Visit= mdy(Visit),
           Days= as.numeric(Visit-lag(Visit)))%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace_na(., 0))->df
  
  return(df)
}

df1 <- days_func(df)

df1

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ClientID Visit       Days
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 00932    2018-11-10     0
2 00932    2018-11-20    10
3 00932    2018-11-25     5
```

Comment: How can I convert this into a function? "Days" column cannot be added if I try to turn this into a function

Comment: @RandomPerson I have added it. Check.

Comment: @RandomPerson did that solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As I assume that you need the day span between dates, not between the date and latest date I propose this:

`dn <- as.numeric(as.Date(Visit))`

The text with dates is consistently converted to date and to number.

`dn2 <- c(dn[1], dn[-length(dn)])`

We prepare the second vector for subtraction as it will work fast. It will have the order of memebers like this:

df   df2

1st  1st

2nd  1st

3rd   2nd

nth  nth-1

`Days <- dn - dn2`

Find the span.